# Did this actor make an appearance in Shazam?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, shazam-2019

During one of the end credits scene in **Shazam! (2019)**, we see that,

> Billy fulfills his promise to Freddy by appearing at the school cafeteria as **Shazam**. 
>  And at the same time, he also invites **Superman** as we see in the final moments **Superman** walking in with his lunch tray.

**NOTE: *The question itself is an apparent spoiler***

So my question is,

> Was it **Henry Cavill** who appeared as **Superman** in Shazam! (*uncredited or otherwise*)?

Answer (score 9):

No. Henry Cavill does not appear in *Shazam!* as he was [unavailable](https://www.inverse.com/article/54562-shazam-ending-explained-directors-talks-about-superman-without-henry-cavill), probably filming *MI: Fallout*.

> “Originally, Superman actually sat down at the table, and they had a little bit of a conversation,” Sandberg says. “But when we were up in Toronto shooting, we couldn’t make it work.”
>
> Production of Shazam! partially took place at a real middle school that was closed “for some sort of a holiday.” “We only had the time we had because we could only shoot when the kids weren’t there,” says the director. “And, of course, I wanted Henry Cavill to pop up. But he was unavailable, which was disappointing.”

Comment: I've edited in the appropriate quote in case the link goes down and changed the link to the appropriate source, as your source was citing something else.

Comment: I was surprised by the mention of MI: Fallout in the answer but the movie was filmed during April 2017~March 2018, while Shazam was shot mostly during March and April 2018.

Comment: I had read in an article online about Henry Cavill being busy with MI:Fallout and probably that being the reason he was unavailable for Shazam!  But cannot find the link when typed the answer. Will update once I find it.